# Find a specific control on a window

Tags: c#, window, progress-bar, findwindow

Im trying to find the value of a specific ProgressBar (msctls_progress32) on a window,

I have found the window with:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);
```

But i cant get the pointer of the ProgressBar with:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string lclassName, string windowTitle);
```

Then once i have the pointer i want to get the value with:

```
public const int PBM_GETPOS = 0x0408;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

The problem is that there are multiple Progress Bars on the window and the progress bar i want the pointer of is inside multiple #32770 (Dialog)

Comment: Since you're using C#, why not use the functionality provided in the UIAutomation namespace? Much easier.

Comment: Could you give me an example.

Comment: We already know what these declarations look like.  What we don't know is what your code looks like.  One possible oversight is that you are forgetting to find the dialog first.

Comment: I do know that i have to look inside all the dialogs first. but if i use the `FindWindowEx` method on on a window to find a dialog. how do i get a specific one if there are are 7 dialogs with the no window captions.

Comment: Are all of those dialogs at the same level, or are they children of one another? You don't have to pass a window caption to the `FindWindowEx` function, it will just return the first matching window that it finds. That will work fine if the dialogs are children of each other. Alternatively, you may want to look into [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx).

Comment: there are a few at the same level and some that are descendants. I'm going to try UIAutomation that you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @CodyGray Got it working with a combination of everything. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question by using `UIAutomation` mixed with `SendMessage` and `FindWindow`

```
//Get parent window.
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Win32.FindWindow(null, "Form1"));
//Get all descendants
AutomationElementCollection elements =  element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);
//loop through descendants
foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in elements)
{
    //if descendant is a progress bar
    if (elementNode.Current.NativeWindowHandle != 0 && elementNode.Current.LocalizedControlType == "progress bar")
    {
        //Show value of the bar.
        MessageBox.Show(Win32.SendMessage((IntPtr)elementNode.Current.NativeWindowHandle, Win32.PBM_GETPOS, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToString(), "Bar value");
    }
}
```